# VB code to subtract a quantity that is in the database when item is scanned in Access

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, events, inventory

I have created a database in Access for when the product is scanned the product, SKU, and inventory that is in the database show up. When scanned the inventory will add one in for the Inventory IN form and subtract one out for the Inventory OUT form. We are now trying to implement a work order into the same forms. When scanned I need the work order number from the WorkOrders table with the quantity of how many needs to be done for that work order. Also, the quantity for the work order needs to decrease by one for each scan. The scan will still increase the inventory by 1.
This is the code for the Inventory IN that I currently have for the After Update event:

```
Private Sub ItemCode_AfterUpdate()

Dim db As DAO.Database

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select InvQty from InventoryManagement where ItemCode =" & Me.ItemCode)

With rst

    .Edit

    !InvQty = !InvQty + 1

    .Update

    .Edit
    
End With

End Sub
```

I need to add code to this to allow for the other part of the form to work and that is to pull up the work order number and the quantity amount for that work order. The tables are InventoryManagement and WorkOrders. My label for the quantity to go is txtBuild. Also, I need a code for when the work order hits 0 then it switches to the next work order. Let me know if it's not possible.

Comment: Ideally, would not do this and instead calculate balances from raw data. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: I've posted something similar to this like 2 weeks ago and was told not to do this this way. I'm confused on why if it works. We are trying to make it as easy as possible for the ones working the floor and just scanning the items will cut out so much time. Is there another way that could also allow the use of scanning?

Comment: Reasons for not doing what you requested are in the referenced link, under the section "Storing the Quantity On Hand Instead". No one is saying shouldn't use scanning as a data entry tool.

Comment: To continue, it is what you do with the scanned input that is at issue. Most anything can be done with enough code. What do you mean by 'pull up' work order number and quantity - open a record or use DLookup()?

Comment: Basically, our system is set up like a POS system. We don't actually have an inventory, we make the product per order. Well, when we over make an item then the item goes into an 'inventory' so to speak and those are used for small quick orders. The Work Order Number and To Build are on a separate table from the rest. I have tried any codes in vba but no luck. I have the DLookUp() function already and it shows. Just need the To Build to decrease on input. For example, we have 100 to make. When scanned, I want the To Build to decrease by 1, so we see 99, 98, 97 .... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured the first part out. I ran the part where the To Build decreases. I ran the same code as posted, but with the data from the other table with On Dirty event instead of the After Update. Just need to figure out the if statement so when the To Build gets to 0 then the next row for the next work order starts with the quantity needed to build.